# If T And T' be two Topology on a same set X and T is strictly finer than T' then "there exit no homeomorphism between them",is a correct statement?

Tags: general-topology

We know lower topology on $\Bbb R$ and usual topology on $\Bbb R$ is not homeomorphic and one is finer than other..now is it true for all topological spaces on a same set where one is strictly finer than other.

Comment: If one space is strictly finer than the other, then their topologies have differing cardinalities. How would this affect the bijectivity of a homeomorphism?

Comment: if two topology induced on a same set and one is strictly finer than other then cardinalty of two topology may be same example lower topology  and standard topology has a same cardinality but they are not homeomorphic

Comment: @gian.  No.  Consider R with base of sets like (r,oo) and of sets  like [r,oo).

Comment: Apologies. I committed a grave blunder by not considering the infinite (and more interesting) case.

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily. It is only immediate that the oidentity map is not a homeomorphism.

Counterexample: Let $X=\Bbb Z$. For $n\in\Bbb Z$, let $A_n=\{\,x\in\Bbb Z\mid x\le n\,\}$. We can consider the topology $T_n$ where $U\subseteq \Bbb Z$ is open if  $A_n\subseteq U$ or $A_n\subseteq \Bbb Z\setminus U$; equivalently, the finiest topology that makes $x\mapsto \max\{n,x\}$ continuous. Then $T_n$ is strictly finer than $T_m$ if $n<m$. Nevertheless $x\mapsto x+m-n$ is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a counterexample:

Let $S$ be the circle $\{z \in \mathbb C : |z|=1\}$ and $I$ be the half-open interval $[0,1)$.

We can add some extra sets to the topology on $S$ to make it homeomorphic to $I$ so the point $0 \in I$ corresponds to $0 \in S$. Namely the sets $\{e^{i\theta}: 0 \le \theta < \epsilon\}$ and $\{e^{i\theta}: -\epsilon < \theta < 0\}$.

Now consider the disjoint union space $X = \ldots \cup I_2 \cup I_1 \cup S_1 \cup S_2 \cup \ldots$ where each $I_i$ is a copy of $I$ and $S_j$ is a copy of S.

By adding some more sets to the topology on $S_1$ we can make $S_1$ homeomorphic to a half open interval $S'$. The resulting space is $\ldots \cup I_2 \cup I_1 \cup S' \cup S_2 \cup \ldots$.

But this space is seen to be homeomorphic to $X$ be remaning $S'$ as $I_1$, $I_1$ as $I_2$ and so on. . . .